# omnet++ installation error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, omnet++

[I have been trying to install omnet++ 4.1 on ubuntu 11.04, but while i enter the "make" command, the following errors are shown which stop the installation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVR1h.png)

Comment: Please don't post just links to images of errors. Please post the main text of the error directly in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are actually trying to install OMNeT++ 4.2. That version of OMNeT++ is too old to be installed with the newer version of GCC installed on your ubuntu version. You should either choose an older Ubuntu version or a newer OMNeT++ version.